# How to catch event when click on link with the same url in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 links:

```
<a href="#link1">First</a>
<a href="#link2">Second</a>
```

And 2 controllers:

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, nextPage, currentPage) {
        alert("ok");
}

app.controller('secondCtrl', function() {}
```

When I go from second link to first link, I see alert. How how to add event, if I stay on 1st link (=firstCtrl) and click on 1st link again?

Attention: I want to get new and old url

Comment: I don't think that it is possible to do it with location change events. Recently I needed something like that, but only for main navigation, so I have used ng-click.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to trigger the alert each time when the first link is clicked, you may need to use `ng-click` attribute rather than `$on('$locationChangeStart')` event listener, which will fire only when url path changes:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <a ng-click="link1()">First</a>
</div>
<div ng-controller="secondCtrl">
    <a ng-click="link2()">Second</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.link1 = function() {
        alert("ok");
    }
});

app.controller('secondCtrl', function() {...});
```

Actually, for this scenario, it is better to change the links to buttons, so that users will expect these elements to hold some local operations instead of new pages(partials).